# How to Download from row click in datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

In the datatable column name "File Name" and "File Path" is given. When the column "File Download" is clicked the file has to be download by merging file path and file name. I want to download by clicking the File download column event

I tried this code,

```
  $('#Datatable tbody').on('click', 'button', function () {
    var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
    return(data[3] + data[2]);
});
```

[image]
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add [rowCallback function](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) to your datatable and change last row cell html to the link needed, you can use data object which will be the data for this row which you will be using to get the file path and name, 
something like this

```
$('#Datatable ').dataTable( {
  "rowCallback": function( row, data, index ) {
         $('td:eq(6)', row).html( '<a href="'+data.filepath+'/'+data.fileName + '" download>Download</a>' );

  }
} );
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: I am happy I helped :)

Comment: Thanks @Munzer it worked.. By using 'code' '<a href="'+data[3]+data[2]+ '" download>Download</a>', i have another issue in controller side, while downloading the file, error occurred 'Network failed'

Comment: you need to provide more info regarding your question, i suggest searching for solution first, if didn't find any, try add one new question :)

Answer (score 1):

You can download the file by wrapping your download button in anchor tag. and in href just concatenate the file path and file name.

`<a href="yourFilePath/fileName" download>Download</a>`

Comment: Yes! but this action can able to download single file. I have dynamic file in all row.

Comment: anchor tag can be populated dynamically too. Same as you are populating the two columns File Path and File Name